# How do I measure the voltage of a bug zapper circuit?

Tags: voltage, oscilloscope

I tried measuring the voltage of a bug zapper circuit with a voltmeter rated up to 600 volts, but when I tried to measure it I got random numbers. I also tried a voltage divider but it was no good.

Somebody said I should get an oscilloscope but I think they're rated up to 400 volts so I'm not sure whether to get one.

How do I measure the voltage from a bug zapper circuit?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [source impedance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/160393/what-is-source-impedance), and what a *capacitor* is? (hint: you're "zap" will be the discharge of a capacitor.) Your question might not have an answer that's as easy as you think.

Comment: Estimate it by measuring the spark length (30 kV per cm as a rough rule). Then come back here with the number and someone might be able to suggest a decent and inexpensive circuit if you need a more accurate value.

Comment: Um no I don't know what source impedance is... I'm trying to learn how this works...

Comment: What is the resistance of your average bug anyway? :)

Comment: @peteblank Go over to YouTube and look up a guy called Big Clive. He's taken apart many of these voltage multiplier devices and explained exactly how they work. He also advises on which ones are safe and which are potentially lethal for humans! There are a lot of badly designed / made ones out there. Note identical circuits are also used in ozone generators, so look for them as well

Comment: You may need a new voltmeter by now, the voltage was most likely well over the 600V.  Best advice: Don't play with it, stay safe and watch the video mentioned in the other comment.